# Google Spreadsheet Custom Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I need to change the background color of a certain range of cells based on a list of values (9 possible) in a single cell. I want the background change to happen across multiple different tabs.

**Range of Cells**: Tab 1(A1:L1, A3:L3, A33:L33) Tab 2(A1:X1, Column C) Tab 3(A1:M1, D5:G5, Column D, Column, G) There are many more, but I think if I see how it's done, I can play with the code enough to make it work!

**Cell**: Tab 2(B3)

**Values**: 'The Reach' = green, 'The North' = light grey, 'The Iron Islands' = dark grey, 'The Riverlands' = dark blue, 'The Vale' = light blue, 'The Crownlands' = dark red, 'The Westerlands' = red, 'The Stormlands' = gold, 'Dorne' = orange

To be honest, the colors don't matter. If you can make the code, I can just tweak the background colors with specific hex code. Also, if possible, could text color be changed as well?

I'm not sure how to begin this, as I have no expertise coding. Would any of you be able to help? Sorry if this is a lot work, I just have NO idea.

[This is the sheet I'm working with.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ox9Bb3YIYFZtbW-stEPpm07-WgHWMDhq11jO0b1xtoU/edit?usp=sharing) I basically just want to change the headers when the region changes.

Comment: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413?rd=1#formulas

Comment: @pnuts, Thought it was relevant? I have no idea. Sorry!

Comment: @hbrmstr, it needs to be a separate code. It doesn't allow me to change entire rows. Only the singular cell, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to trigger colors changes, I would give the [built-in conditional formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413?hl=en) a try first. If you need help formulating a statement after reviewing that, there's already numerous examples / threads in the official [Docs Product Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/docs) that use the "Custom formula is" box.

At this point, the only reason to get a script involved is to trigger some thing more advanced to happen when your cell value changes like sending an email or moving a row.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a 'general guide' (ie I can't be bothered to set up and explain nine different colours in three different tabs and multiple ranges). First give B3 in `Holdfast Information` a name - say `Region`. Then apply a conditional formatting rule to `Income` Row 2 of say:

```
Custom formula is =row()=2 Format: Text Colour: Black, Range: 2:2.
```

(To allow the next rule to apply to A1:L3.) Then:

```
Custom formula is =indirect("Region")="The Westerlands" Format: Text Colour: of your choice, Background Colour: Red, Range: A1:L3.
```

As an aside, you should perhaps be applying a lookup rather than that horrible formula in B3.

Comment: No problem. If the first answer doesn't work, I'll likely resort to making a script.

Also, I completely agree with you. I completely forgot that lookup was an actual thing. Too late to change it now, though.